# What is External representation of time in Sequential learning?

Tags: neural-network, rnn, sequence, sequential-pattern-mining

I am reading the literature on sequential learning and it is often mention that in order to handle sequential/temporal data, there two categories of work in sequential learning

1. External Representation of Time
2. Internal Representation of Time

I am not able to understand the difference between two, for example in the paragraphs below, it is hinted that external representation can be inserted directly by `preprocessing time through a time to space transformation`. Following example is given to elaborate this.

> ```
> For instance, one effective way of constructing a spatial representation of temporally-
> occurring information (which is not only limited to neural computing) is to create
> the power spectrum of the incoming information and use it as a static input image.
> ```

Is there any simple and intuitive example to understand this? I cant get time to space transformation or power spectrum thing.